# julia fast lookup of a list of array values

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a lookup table in the form of a 2d array and a list of indices (in the form of two 1d arrays xs, ys) at which I would like to evaluate the lookup table. How to accomplish this in a fast manner?

It looks like a standard problem, however I found nothing about looking up array values at a general list of indices (e.g. not a cartesian product) in the [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#indexing). I tried

```
result = zeros((10^6,))
for i in [1:10^6]
    x = xs[i]
    y = ys[i]
    result[i] = lookup[x, y]
end
```

Besides looking a bit cumbersome, this code is also 10 times slower then an equivalent numpy code. Also it looks like a standard problem, however I found nothing about looking up array values at a general list of indices (e.g. not a cartesian product) in the [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#indexing).

So what would be a fast alternative to the above code?

Comment: It's slow only because it's not inside a function.

Comment: ok avoid global variables in speedtest lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `broadcast_getindex` (see http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.broadcast_getindex).

Otherwise, it looks like your code should be pretty efficient if you just change `[1:10^6]` to `1:10^6`.

Comment: Also be sure to wrap it in a function instead of running in global scope. That's going to be dog slow: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-global-variables

Comment: Thanks, wrapping it in a function and iterating over a UnitRange instead of array gives roughly same speed as in numpy. Will look into broadcast_getindex next.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the updated links for `Base.getindex` (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.getindex). The broadcasted implementation found [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/broadcast.jl).